# How do you change lifted types back to Scala types when using Slick lifted embedding?

Tags: scala, slick

How do you 'un-lift' a value inside a query in [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com) when using lifted embedding? I was hoping a 'get', 'toLong' or something like that may do the trick, but no such luck.

The following code does not compile:

```
  val userById = for {
     uid <- Parameters[Long]
     u <- Users if u.id === uid
  } yield u

  val userFirstNameById = for {
     uid <- Parameters[Long]
     u <- userById(uid)
     ---------------^
     // type mismatch;  found   : scala.slick.lifted.Column[Long]  required: Long
  } yield u.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, for 2 reasons:

> 1) with `val` this is happening at compile time, there is no `Long`
>   value `uid`. `userById(uid)` binds a `Long uid` to the compile time
>   generated prepared statement, and then `.list`, `.first`, etc. invoke
>   the query.
>
> 2) the other issue is as soon as you `Parameter`ize a query,
>   composition is no longer possible -- it's a limitation dating back to
>   ScalaQuery.

Your best bet is to delay `Parameter`ization until the final composed query:

```
val forFooBars = for{
  f <- Foos
  b <- Bars if f.id is b.fooID
} yield(f,b)
val allByStatus = for{ id ~ active <- Parameters[(Long,Boolean)]
  (f,b) <- forFooBars if (f.id is id) && (b.active is active)
} yield(f,b)

def findAllByActive(id: Long, isActive: Boolean) = allByStatus(id, isActive).list
```

At any rate, in your example you could just as well do:

```
val byID = Users.createFinderBy(_.id)
```

The only way that I know to get this kind of thing to work is wrap the query `val` in a `def` and pass in a runtime variable, which means Slick has to re-generate the sql on every request, and no prepared statement is sent to underlying DBMS. In some cases you have to do this, like passing in a `List(1,2,3)` for `inList`.

```
def whenNothingElseWorks(id: Long) = {
  val userFirstNameById = for {u <- userById(id.bind)} yield u.name
}
```

Comment: Oh bugger ;-) Pretty stupid that I forgot the query was assigned to the val at compile time. Thanks for the nice explanation. I'm just experimenting with query composition in Slick. What I'm actually after is the best way to filter query results at runtime and then build other queries on top of that. I also normally use code similar to your last example, but I just wanted to see if I could find an alternative.

Comment: As of now we can't compose parameterized queries; if and when that functionality is available, much boilerplate will be removed. Just build up query blocks and slice & dice into a final paramterized query.